# How can I ensure that an iframe inherits the browser mode and document mode of its parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo, doctype

I have a Web page whose purpose is to be embedded in various other pages via an iframe. Those pages have different doctypes and are used on different browsers.

For consistency, how can I ensure that the iframe always inherits the browser mode and document mode of its parent?

A typical example: I am using dojo, which chooses the chart rendering method (svg/vml/canvas/silverlight) at runtime, depending on the browser and document modes. I want to make sure the rendering is consistent between parent and iframe.

For the record, all pages are in the same domain.

Comment: You can't enforce this kind of dependency between an iframe and its parent document. The browser renders the two documents completely independently and only allows *some* intercommunication between their window objects if the (sub)domains are the same. If you want them to be in the same document mode, use the same doctype.

Comment: @Graham thx. Well, I guess this would make a good answer...

Comment: You could always try to use a `ContentPane` toload your embedded page. With the `href` attribute you can load one HTML page into another. You could "see" it as a JavaScript version of an iframe. But since both documents are rendered in the parent document, it will probably inherit these modes.